# Installing KDE on Ubuntu Natty from cdrom

Tags: ubuntu, kde, apt, software-installation

Currently I have Ubuntu 11.04 - Natty, with Unity as the default environment; but I just want to install KDE along-side it, and I don't have perfect bandwidth. So I took Kubuntu 11.04 cdrom from my friend and inserted it to my cdrom. After running `apt-cdrom add` it prints out this:

```
Using CD-ROM mount point /media/apt/
Identifying.. [ce3c168e46b345c6adc05b209f603d08-2]
Scanning disc for index files..

E: Unable to stat the mount point /media/Kubuntu\04011.04\040amd64/ - stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Unable to stat the mount point /media/Kubuntu\04011.04\040amd64/ - stat (2: No such file or directory)
```

I have tested the cdrom for the infections but it was just ok. What's the problem?

UPDATE: my friend just asked me to put print my `fstab` entry here. as expected, my cdrom device is not listed in it but here it is:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=d8caef34-1670-4525-a5b5-df889f62aa1e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=7b71d3a8-bbea-477e-8b04-0c9651d0e12e /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /windows was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=CC523DE8523DD7C2 /windows        ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=3a281560-f3aa-4795-b396-0810e1eb15e2 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: What do you mean by "tested the cdrom for the infections"? Was this CD verified to work by anyone else? My first thought is to check the iso's md5sum against that listed on the site (assuming it is listed), but it seems to you didn't burn it yourself? What happens if you try to mount the cd? Also, can you post your /etc/fstab entry for your cdrom? Unlikely to be the problem, but no harm.

Comment: when you put the cd in the machine and reboot, it shows a menu offering to try kubuntu, test memory, boot from 1st hard disk and check cd for infections. i think with this thing done, there is no need for a md5 check; am I wrong? also i think when a disk passes this test, it is supposed to work. i have to mention that it boots up as live disk without problem. yeah, I have burnt it and it mounts without any problems. I will update the question with fstab. thanx for your attention ;-)

Comment: Ok. I'm unsure how it works without an entry in `/etc/fstab`, but maybe it has been automated. So, what mount point does it use? Maybe add your entry for mount and remove the `/etc/fstab`. And the path it cannot stat - does that path exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lol...

Sorry to laugh but, chances are you are using the wrong kind of CD. You need the alternate CD, and from what I understand in your question, it seems you are actually using the live CD.

Get an alternate installer CD or download KDE from the repository.

Comment: aah... thanx bro ;-)